# C2057: expected constant expression

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, constants

I can't compile this on VS2013, but it does compile on gcc 4.7.2. I understand VC++ is lagging behind GCC and CLang in terms of features, but what feature is it exactly and if not this is a bug, isn't?

```
template <int N>
struct factorial
{
    static const long value;
    static const long previous = factorial<N - 1>::value; //C2057: expected constant expression
};

template <int N>
const long factorial<N>::value = N*factorial<N - 1>::value;

template <>
struct factorial<0>
{
    static const long value = 1;
};
```

Please don't tell me how I can get a workaround of this issue, cause this is not a production code neither I need one. For example I can define value in the class and the problem is solved, but let's assume I have to define it outside the class (VC2013 still doesn't support constexpr)

Comment: Any reason why `previous` has an in-class initialisation and `value` does not?

Comment: Let's say I am not able to define 'value' in-class cause VC2013 doesn't have constexpr cause I am calling a function

Comment: Well, expressions involving non-constexpr functions aren't constants, so C2057 sounds exactly right in that situation. You probably should show us the real problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSVC doesn't have a proper two-phase template compilation. GCC correctly sees `factorial<N - 1>::value` as a dependent name and resolves in the second phase, but MSVC has to do it in the first phase.

Comment: So is it a bug or a missing feature?

Comment: @ОгњенШобајић Given the length of time two phase resolution has been part of the standard (it was in C++98), I think you'd have to consider it a bug.